# Exporting in Gephi doesn't keep labels colors

Tags: gephi

When I export my graph in PDF or SVG (in gephi 0.9.2, linux version), the nodes *labels* colors I've set are not kept (it's white or black). Strangely enough, the *nodes* colors are correct.
I know that preview and work window are different, but is there a workaround? Does the nightly 0.9.3 solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting "original" into node labels > colors in the preview.